# Return UpdatePanel to default state

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPnl1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Tb1" Text="TextBox Default">
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Lbl1" Text="Label Default">
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

now, I'm doing some stuff, updating it in AJAX and now i want a command that return the default state (With the 'Default' texts to appear).

is there a way to do it without refreshing the page?

**Edit:**
I may have not been clear. this is a form that can be updated from code behind, however, sometimes I want the regular form to appear.
This is a case of Edit / New Record. 
When a user Edits, I load date to this form, but if after editing some record the user wants to enter a new record, I want the default view to appear.

Comment: The process is not clear. You post back asynchronously, then you update the `TextBox` and the `Label` from codebehind on the server. After that you want to "return" the default values of both controls to the client? So do you want to change it from their default state or not?

Comment: Thank you, just edited the post. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: After your edit I would suggest to use a FormView.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the FormView is mainly used in GridView?

Comment: No, a `FormView` is an independent web-databound control to display a single record(as opposed to a `Repeater`,`GridView`,`DataList` etc). It has three [modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewmode.aspx): `ReadOnly`, `Edit` and  `Insert`. You can use the same control-id's for every template. There are several tutorials available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by @Tim Schmelter, using a FormView did the trick.
Thanks

Comment: You should consider to accept your own answer. But maybe you want to show how you have i mplemented your scenario with a `FormView` so that other visitors can benefit from your answer too.

Comment: I will once it's done. I just checked it on test mode.
Thank you